# Receiving at GET the index.html of the Client project rather than the json data from the Server

Tags: c#, blazor

I am new to C# & Blazor and I appreciate your help!

I have started two new projects, one Server Project (.NET 5.0) and one Blazor WebAssembly Client project. The problem is that I am trying to GET json data from the Server, but I am receiving the exception:

*Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.).*

After debugging, I find that the Content of my returned HttpResponseMessage (converted to string) contains the *index.html* of the client project. More specifically, the variable "responseString" of the method "Deserialize" inside the "HttpService.cs" (shown below) contains the *index.html* of the client project instead the json data from the server.

The server sends the data properly. I have confirmed it with swagger.

The **method** in my Blazor WebAssembly App for **getting data**:

```
public class ContractsServices : IContractsServices
{
    private readonly IHttpService _httpService;
    private readonly string url = "api/Contracts";
    public ContractsUIRepository(IHttpService httpService)
    {
        _httpService = httpService;
    }
    
    public async Task<List<ContractDTO>> GetAllContracts()
    {
        var response = await _httpService.Get<List<ContractDTO>>(url);
        if (!response.IsSucceed)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(await response.GetBodyOfResponse());
        }
        return response.Response;
    }
}
```

My **HttpService.cs**:

```
public class HttpService : IHttpService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public HttpService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseWrapper<T>> Get<T>(string url)
    {
        var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var response = await Deserialize<T>(httpResponseMessage);
            return new HttpResponseWrapper<T>(true, response, httpResponseMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpResponseWrapper<T>(false, default, httpResponseMessage);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<T> Deserialize<T>(HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
    {
        var responseString = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
    }
}
```

The **HttpResponseWrapper.cs**:

```
public class HttpResponseWrapper<T>
{
    public bool IsSucceed { get; set; }
    public T Response { get; set; }
    public HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessage { get; set; }

    public HttpResponseWrapper(bool isSucceed, T response, HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
    {
        IsSucceed = isSucceed;
        Response = response;
        HttpResponseMessage = httpResponseMessage;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetBodyOfResponse()
    {
        return await HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

My **Program.cs** in the client project:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        builder.Services.AddScoped<IHttpService, HttpService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IContractsServices, ContractsServices>();

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time and your help!!!

Comment: You have a URL mismatch. Compare the exact server URL (from swagger) with what the client sends.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. I solved it. I had to change in my Program.cs file at the client project the "BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)" to the base URL of my server project. I had tried it before but then I ran into a CORS exception. So additionally I had to call "AllowAnyOrigin()" in the CORS policy on my server project. Before that, I had "policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44337/")" where "https://localhost:44337/" is my client base URL but it didn't work and I dont know why.